# How to partially required a tuple - while preserving the labels

Tags: typescript

I would like a type to ensure the beginning of a Tuple is required but not all of itn while retaining the labels.
Is they re a way to define `RequiredFrom` such as?

```js
type RequiredFrom<T extends any[], From extends number> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key]
  // how to ensure required if key does not extends `${From}` and 
  // not in all cases like when using -?
  // From is guaranteed to contains all indexes from from up to T['length'] - 1
}

type test = RequiredFrom<[a?: 1, b?: 1, c?: 1, d?: 1], 2 | 3> 
// Result: [a?: 1, b?: 1, c?: 1, d?: 1]
// Desired Target: [a: 1, b: 1, c?: 1, d?: 1]
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXAlgJwgEwGKoPYFsAeAFSggA9gIA7DAZygENqQBtAXQBoocCzKa9KNUT4ARhFQA+KAF4oAbwBQUKKwDWEEFGTUomkLgBmUYuwBcpjVvYqoAentQAFrgDuUYLjLU6idFDoSGiYOiYGUBi4EAzUuMD8VLQMAAYAJAq8+AC+KUy0UHaOwvE6eowANhVQAMaMdDFQFciaUG7ONFCIdLoA5lAAtAD8RU5ZOgy9iIyozFShXrW41MCMugyV1boYFI1GePhQ+3yIYJ7exKwA5BU0vcDOV+yDUACMStlKSqCQnjEJ8jgwXQ2AOhFYjCGlle3DEULe3Bq8JhkWRXCgACYoAAfKAAZhkSmKcD8FWAlghyNhVNqNIwaKJTgAIjEQhhTDNehByWpGNDYfzaYL6dD2EA)

Comment: @jcalz that approach do not preserve labels - while the forme using a `Required` like type does - if it'n not possible i'll use yours - but if it is it would be better (and work for larger tuples)

Comment: @jcalz I've specified the need to preserve labels in the question - for the rest i want to make a multiple use case type - so can't know in advance which size i'll need to support

Comment: Is they're a way to achieve it while preserving the labels ?

Comment: I do not have an answer to your question except what i've already told
truth be told it's unlikely your type will break anytime soon, but i would like to find a way to preserve the labels if any

Comment: This is what i started with but it will break for tuples like `[a: 1, b?: 2, ...c: 3[]]` this is why i wanted to construct a type the same way the base type `Required` is build to allow lables in aby case

Comment: If I understand correctly you already came up with essentially the suggestion I made but didn't post about it or mention it for some reason.  I'm going to disengage now, since it's unlikely that you'll accept any answer I can come up with.  Good luck!

Comment: Basically what i'm hopping to be able to do is to condiationaly apply operator `-?` on keys based on condition -but it seems from your answer is a no can't do ?

Comment: @jcalz sorry you took it this way i didnt intend to upset you - the fault is mine i didn't make my requirements clear from the get go

Answer (score 2):

You may split it into two arrays and then merge back https://tsplay.dev/N9Yp1N

```
type RequiredFrom<T extends any[], From extends number> =
  [
    ...DropLastUntilN<Required<T>, From>,
    ...Extract<Partial<DropFirstN<Required<T>, From>>, any[]>,
  ]

type test = RequiredFrom<[a?: 1, b?: 1, c?: 1, d?: 1], 2>
//   ^?
// Result: type test = [a: 1, b: 1, c?: 1, d?: 1]
// Desired Target:     [a: 1, b: 1, c?: 1, d?: 1]


type DropLastUntilN<A extends any[], N extends number> =
  | A extends { length: N | 0 } ? A
  : A extends [...infer F, infer L] ? DropLastUntilN<F, N>
  : []

type DropFirstN<A extends any[], N extends number, Count extends any[] = []> =
  | Count extends { length: N } ? A
  : A extends [infer F, ...infer L] ? DropFirstN<L, N, [...Count, 0]>
  : []
```